# How to blend 2 transparency layers?

Tags: math, alpha, alphablending, rgba, alpha-transparency

For example we have 2 transparency layers: first is `black (0, 0, 0, 0.75)` and second is `white (255, 255, 255, 0.64)`. I don't know how to blend them.

But I know how to blend one opaque and one transparent layers. It's look like this: https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/media/math/render/svg/1e35c32f13d5eedc7ac21e9e566796dd048a31e6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that the background colour is `(C, 1)` (RGB, A), the first layer is `(A, s)` and the second layer `(B, t)`. Applying the blending equation twice:

```
C' = t * B + (1-t) * [s * A + (1-s) * C]

     = [t * B + (1-t) * s * A] + (1-t) * (1-s) * C
```

We can see that the new **effective** blending coefficient is `1 - (1-s) * (1-t)`. To get the combined transparency colour, divide the first term by this:

```
r := 1 - (1-s) * (1-t)

D := [t * B + (1-t) * s * A] / r

--> C' = r * D + (1-r) * C
```

i.e. the new effective transparency layer is given by `(D, r)`.

In your example the values would be `D = (179, 179, 179)` and `r = 0.91`.

Comment: thx, but can you explain this formula: `r := 1 - (1-s) * (1-t)` I understand what is it general alpha. But I don't understand operations in this formula.

Comment: @MaximPro In the first equation block I showed that the coefficient of `C` is `(1-s) * (1-t)`; this corresponds to `"1 - A"` in the Wikipedia equation, since `C` corresponds to `"B"` as the background colour. Therefore the effective alpha `r` (corresponding to `"A"`) is 1 minus this coefficient.

Comment: Once again, I thoughtfully read your post and figured out, thank you.

Comment: I still have one more question. Why do we divide on effective alpha (`/r`)? Why not multiply?

Comment: @MaximPro sorry for the late reply. It is because the multiplication you are talking about happens during *mixing*, whereas we need to compute the effective foreground colour, which requires the reverse process. Anyway the algebra itself should make it clear.

Comment: But you did not explain why division is used.

Comment: @MaximPro **I did**. We must find the foreground colour from the mixed colour, which is the exact **reverse** process to the mixing equation you linked; hence we must divide by the alpha `"A"` (`= r`) instead of multiply. In terms of the algebra above, we equate `[t * B + (1-t) * s * A]` to the foreground mixing term `"F * A"` (`= r * D`), so to obtain `D` we must divide by `r`.