# Math Formula for calculating the resulting colour of a transparent layer with a multiply blend over another layer

Tags: math, alpha, alphablending, rgba, alpha-transparency

I have been trying to get a correct result in a language agnostic way. currently using excel to pin it down. I have attached an image of my current status. In this example I am starting with the background colour of `#7D01FF` and and over source colour of `#FFFF01` at 50% opacity the resulting colour is `#7D0180`

with formula

`=( (E13/255)* ( (D13/255)*( (D$16/255) + ( ((C13/255)*(C$16/255)) * (1-(D$16/255) ))) /  ( (D$16/255) + ((C$16/255) * (1-(D$16/255))) )) ) *255`

aka

C<sub>b</sub> * (c<sub>s</sub>*α<sub>s</sub>) + ((c<sub>a</sub>*α<sub>a</sub>) * (1-α<sub>s</sub>))/α<sub>o</sub>

where

α<sub>o</sub> is α<sub>s</sub>+α<sub>a</sub>*(1-α<sub>s</sub>)

and

Blend<sub>(multiply)</sub> is C<sub>b</sub>*C<sub>s</sub>

C being the chanels R, G, B each as a seperate calculation.

I have assumed (as I am unsure what else to do) that for this caclulation the initial transparency is calculated as if on a white back ground.

instead of getting the expected purple I am getting a red with the values `rgba(125,1,1,255)` or `#7D0101`

[excel spreadsheet representing the source background, and formulas in each channel red, green, and blue, plus the alpha values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sOEGZ.png)

I am self teaching (largely and referring to things like: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_compositing
https://www.w3.org/TR/compositing-1/#simplealphacompositing
I also looked at
[How to blend 2 transparency layers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53321906/how-to-blend-2-transparency-layers)
and it is similar but does not yield the correct result in my situation.

I am trying to set up the basis of a Design token catalogue for a design system based (loosely) around material design and have a BFa with an on and off history with computer programming, So please be kind to me.

**update**

Maybe I am not getting it but this doesn't arrive at the result I am expecting. I will update further in a little bit.

**Update**

So the result I am getting is RGB, a (201 180 180, 75%) When the result I am expecting is RGB, a (126 0 8, 100%). I am obtaining these values from Illustrator in RGB color space.

I think there is another step I am missing.  I will list the equations below and include an image that may offer some context.

a = RGB(255, 255, 1) on upper layer & the layer alpha = 50% Multiply blend

b = RGB(125, 1, 255) layer alpha 100% Normal blend

t assumed to be 50% for even blend

Alpha of R = (1-0.5)*(127.5/255) + 0.5*(255/255)

Color of R = [rgb] = √( (1 - t) * (c1[n])<sup>2</sup> + t * c2[n]<sup>2</sup>)

R<sub>[rgb]</sub> = [ √( 0.5 * 65025 + 0.5 * 15625),  √( 0.5 * 65025 + 0.5 * 1),   √( 0.5 * 1 + 0.5 * 65025)

alpha = (1-0.5)*(127.5/255) + 0.5*(255/255)

R<sub>[rgb]</sub> = [201  180  180] with alpha 75%

I don't know what I am missing, or doing wrong.

[An image providing colors and context of above mentioned formulas.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s7DCC.jpg)

Comment: You're going to have to clean up this text a bit, because HTML doesn't work inside code blocks, and you also seem to have plain text inside code lines.

Comment: Also, it sounds like you want [Algorithm for Additive Color Mixing for RGB Values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/726549/algorithm-for-additive-color-mixing-for-rgb-values), specifically [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29321264/740553) to that question.

Comment: Maybe I am not getting it but this doesn't arrive at the result I am expecting. I will update further in a little bit.